# Spring 4 RestController services not getting called from jsp in web application

Tags: spring-mvc, web-applications, spring-4, spring-restcontroller

I have developed a web-application using Spring4,maven,jquery,tomcat.
I am using java config class instead of web.xml and spring applicationContext.xml. Using @RestController instead of @Controller in controller classes for decoupled application. Don't want to use @Controller as in this case I have to return view name and model which I don't want to.

Issue:-
My web-application start fine and dashboard.js is called from dashboard.jsp.
But when I try to call DashboardController.java service '/dashboard/getDashboardDetails' it gives 404 page not found error. 
No error in eclipse or tomcat console.

**Filter Class:-**

```
package com.me.configuration;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("Filtering on...........................................................");
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

public void destroy() {}

}
```

**Configuration Class**
    package com.me.configuration;

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.me")
public class ManageBudgetConfiguration {

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/pages/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    return viewResolver;
}

}
```

**Initializer Class**

```
package com.me.configuration;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class ManageBudgetInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {


@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { ManageBudgetConfiguration.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    Filter [] singleton = { new CORSFilter()};
    return singleton;
}

}
```

**Controller Class**

```
package com.me.controller;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

import com.me.model.DashboardBean;
import com.me.model.User;
import com.me.service.DashboardServiceInf;
import com.me.service.UserService;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dashboard")
public class DashboardController {


@Autowired
UserService userService;  //Service which will do all data retrieval/manipulation work

@Autowired
DashboardServiceInf dashboardService; 


/**
 * This service returns Dashboard data details
 * @return String
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/getDashboardDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<DashboardBean>> getDashBoardDetails() {
    System.out.println("Dashboardcontroller : getDashBoardDetails");
    String userId ="rahil";
    List<DashboardBean> dashboardBeanList = dashboardService.getDashBoardDetails(userId);
    if(dashboardBeanList.isEmpty()){
        return new ResponseEntity<List<DashboardBean>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<List<DashboardBean>>(dashboardBeanList, HttpStatus.OK);
}

}
```

**dashboard.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Manage Expense</title>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script type ="text/javascript" src="./resources/javascript/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Dashboard Charts -->
<script src="resources/javascript/js/dashboardCharts.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script type ="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("\tdashboard.jsp");

    $.ajax({ 
        url : "resources/javascript/system/dashboard.js",
        dataType : "script",
        cache : true        
    }).done(function(){ 
        console.log("inside done....");
        me.dashboard.onload();
    });

});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**dashboard.js**

```
me = new Object();

if (typeof me.dashboard == 'undefined') {
me.dashboard = function() {
    return {

        msgArray:[], // variable for  checking same message

        /**
         * @author rahikhan
         * @description Function to be called once the dashboard loaded.
         */
        onload : function(){
            console.log("dashboard.js : onload..called without error");
            me.dashboard.getDashboardDetails();
        },

        getDashboardDetails : function(){
            console.log("dashboard.js : getDashboardDetails...");
            var promise = $.ajax({
                async: true,
                url: "dashboard/getDashboardDetails.htm",
                type: "GET",
                datatype: "json",
                accept: "application/json",
            }).done(function(result) {
                result = JSON.parse(result);
                console.log("\tresult : " + result);
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                console.log("\tgetDashboardDetails : Application Exception Occured " );
            });
            return promise;
        },

    }
}();
```

}

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.me</groupId>
    <artifactId>manageBudget</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>manageBudget</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <jackson.version>2.5.3</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- System Related dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                        <warName>manageBudgetWar</warName>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml> 
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <finalName>manageBudget</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Why do you have 3 scripts for jquery? Why do you load your js file dynamically instead of statically? Why do you request dashboard/getDashboardDetails.htm although your controller is mapped to dashboard/getDashboardDetails, and doesn't return html, but json?

Comment: @JB Nizet 3 jquery scripts is typing mistake. corrected it.

Comment: @JB Nizet  1. 3 jquery scripts is typing mistake. corrected it.  2. Adding script statically will make any difference. Should I change it?  3. DashboardController.java  path is "/dashboard" and getDashBoardDetails() method's path is "/getDashboardDetails"  and I am trying to call this service as <baseurl>/dashboard/getDashboardDetails.htm. This service returns json which  will populate fields on dashbard.jsp dynamically. Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Again: your controller is mapped to `/dashboard//getDashboardDetails`. Your request is sent to `/dashboard/getDashboardDetails.htm`. Don't you see a difference? The `.htm` suffix shouldn't be there. And it doesn't even make sense since `.htm` is typically used to refer to a resource returning HTML. But your resource returns JSON. Remove that suffix.

Comment: can you explain how the url 'dashboard//getDashboardDetails' is being formed with //?

Comment: The `//` is a typo in my previous comment. Concentrate on the suffix, as I explained.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on above issue since I posted it on this forum(about a month ago). At last, I was able to resolve the issue. 
Here is what I missed intially and corrected it to solve the issue:-

**1.** ManageBudgetConfiguration.java: 
I missed to extend WebMvcConfigurerAdapter in ManageBudgetConfiguration class.

```
public class ManageBudgetConfiguration **extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter**{ ... }
```

**2.** Override addResourceHandlers(...) method in ManageBudgetConfiguration.java class 
   to include static ui resources such as js,css etc. My javascript and css files are in `<basedir>/webapp/resources/` folders

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
```

above method is the equivalent code for application-contex mapping:-

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/theme-new/" />
```

**3a.** Include Gson in pom. Gson is google lib to convert Java Object to JSON and vice-versa.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**3b** Change return type of rest-endpoints methods:-

```
return new ResponseEntity<List<DashboardBean>>(dashboardBeanList, HttpStatus.OK)
    to
return response;
where response is json string
eg


@RequestMapping(value = "/getDashboardDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String getDashBoardDetails(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("Dashboardcontroller : getDashBoardDetails1");
        String response = null;
        String userId ="rahil";

        List<DashboardBean> dashboardBeanList = dashboardService.getDashBoardDetails(userId);
        response = new Gson().toJson(dashboardBeanList);
        return response;
    }
```